# iterate through a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am aiming to interpret An I&C logical diagram data which are exported as XML data, which I parse with python and then create pandas dataframes containing these information.
The idea now is that I have a pandas dataframe from which I want to extract and rearrange certain data based on the structure of the df.
As an example:

```
 guid1 guid2
 A865  OR4
 A875  OR4
 OR4   JN1397
```

A865 and A875 are 2 inputs/sensors, OR4 is a logical gate and JN1397 is the output.
What I want to achieve is to iterate through my df and check if there is a relation between the values, for my example the relation between the 2 first rows is that A865 and A875 are both related by OR4, which then gives us the output JN1397 :
Expected Output in python code is :

```
A865, A875, OR4, JN1397
```

Any ideas please ? I really couldn't think about something